# TabHost with Zoom Property

Tags: android, zooming, android-tabhost

How to set the zoom property to tabHost. I've listed some items in listview. That listview displays on tabhost. When, i press any item, that'll displays in another layout with zoom property. How can i achieve this? Anyone guide me. Thanks in Advance.

**Edit**

TabHost also displayed, when the another layout redirected. So, the details of item can be show the detail within the tabhost.

**Update**

Finally, i've successfully displays the item's detail in another layout and, the another layout is also displayed in same tabHost using [this](http://blog.csdn.net/koupoo/article/details/7002001) blog. Now, i need to implement the zoom property for this layout. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by zoom property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by my own. I just work with my tabHost using Parent & child activity as by this [article.](http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) And, i've pass the values to webview & set the zoom properties to that Webview. It hopes helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly, you need [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html). You can have a fragment with list view and when an item is clicked you replace the fragment with the one containing your item details.

**Edit** Although, I'm not sure what you mean by zoom property. But if you're talking about zooming the list view item that's been clicked - i'm pretty sure you can create a zoom-like transition effect for switching fragments.